# Compare a date in php and show the result

Tags: php, sql-server

I've got the following function on my website:

```
function Active()
{
    ............

$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT PremiumDays, PremiumStartTime FROM Premium WHERE AccountID = ?', $_SESSION['AccountID']);
if ($num_rows == -1)
{
$this->Error('ERROR');
$db->getError();
return;
}

$data = $db->doRead();
$data['Status'] = $num_rows == 0 ? '<:SHOW_PREMIUM_STATUS:>' : '<b><font size="2" color="red">Premium is active - <%Days_Remaining%> days remaining.</font></b>';

$replace = array
(
'account_status'        => $data['Status'],
'days_remaining'        => number_format($data['PremiumDays'])
);

$this->content = Template::Load('account-template', $replace);
}
```

`PremiumDays` column contains numbers like `10`,`15`,`30` etc.

`PremiumStartTime` contains a date in this format `2018-12-17 21:13:00`

What I am trying to achieve is to show the actual days of premium remaining with `days_remaining`. So, I believe I need to substract from `PremiumDays` the days that passed since the premium started based on the second column `PremiumStartTime`.

Something like this:

```
days_remaining = PremiumDays - (NumberOfDaysSincePremiumStarted(DateToday - PremiumStartTime))
```

I will greatly appreciate if you can help me out with this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @tim - I am not sure how to implement it correctly in PHP. That's the problem. I will greatly appreciate if you can help me out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Might want to take a peek [here](http://bobby-tables.com) before you get a visit from bobby tables.

Comment: @tim - Exactly, I am not sure how to be done correctly as well. :(

Comment: You would use DATEDIFF. The documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). And to get the current time it is simply getdate()

Comment: @SeanLange - So, in that case first I will have to convert my date format, for example `2018-12-17 21:13:00` to seconds because I can't see any full date format as `datepart` in the documentation to compare?

Comment: No need. It will do an implicit conversion from date to datetime.