# Substract a date compared to current date and show actual remaining days

Tags: php, sql-server

This is my function below:

```
function Active()
{
    ............

$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT PremiumDays, PremiumStartTime FROM Premium WHERE AccountID = ?', $_SESSION['AccountID']);
if ($num_rows == -1)
{
$this->Error('ERROR');
$db->getError();
return;
}

$data = $db->doRead();
$data['Status'] = $num_rows == 0 ? '<:SHOW_PREMIUM_STATUS:>' : '<b><font size="2" color="red">Premium is active - <%Days_Remaining%> days remaining.</font></b>';

$replace = array
(
'account_status'        => $data['Status'],
'days_remaining'        => number_format($data['PremiumDays'])
);

$this->content = Template::Load('account-template', $replace);
}
```

`PremiumDays` column contains numbers like `10`,`15`,`30` etc.

`PremiumStartTime` contains a date in this format `2018-12-17 21:13:00`

What I am trying to achieve is to show the actual days of premium remaining with `days_remaining`. So, I believe I need to substract from `PremiumDays` the days that passed since the premium started based on the second column `PremiumStartTime`.

Something like that I believe, however, I am not sure how to implement it correctly in PHP. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
days_remaining = PremiumDays - (NumberOfDaysSincePremiumStarted(DateToday - PremiumStartTime))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare a date in php and show the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53858355/compare-a-date-in-php-and-show-the-result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the difference in PHP, you can create a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object using [`DateTime::diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) between the current time (output of [`date_create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php)) and a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object created from your `PremiumStartTime` variable. You can then access the [`days`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#dateinterval.props.days) value of this object to get the total number of days from the `PremiumStartTime` to the current time. For example:

```
$data['PremiumStartTime'] = '2018-12-12 21:13:00';
$data['PremiumDays'] = 20;
$days_remaining = $data['PremiumDays'] - date_create($data['PremiumStartTime'])->diff(date_create())->days;
echo number_format($days_remaining);
```

Output:

```
13
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/iVbuP)

Comment: Thanks! So, I won't touch my other code but only this line: `'days_remaining'        => $data['PremiumDays'] - date_create($data['PremiumStartTime'])->diff(date_create())->days` It works as I can see. Is it safe?

Comment: Yes you would just change that one line. What do you mean by "is it safe?"

Comment: It's perfectly fine. Ignore the safe part. ;-) Now, I will have to figure it out how to make non negative numbers to display. Because currently If `PremiumDays` is `20` and there are more than 20 days passed since the `PremiumStartTime` it will display it with a negative number like `Remaining days -5` for example. But that's for another question I believe because you already answered me in a perfect way. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the DB as follows:

```
//SQL Server
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT PremiumDays, PremiumStartTime, 
             (PremiumDays - datediff(day,PremiumStartTime,getdate())) DaysRemaining 
              FROM Premium WHERE AccountID = ?', $_SESSION['AccountID']);


//MySQL
$num_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT PremiumDays, PremiumStartTime, 
             (PremiumDays - datediff(now(),PremiumStartTime)) DaysRemaining 
              FROM Premium WHERE AccountID = ?', $_SESSION['AccountID']);
```

Then:

```
$replace = array
(
'account_status'        => $data['Status'],
'days_remaining'        => $data['DaysRemaining']
);
```

Proof here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xzuc89C9gQUHpdTTy9M4vf/0

Or if you really want to do it in PHP:

```
$replace = array
(
'account_status'        => $data['Status'],
'days_remaining'        => $data['PremiumDays'] - date_diff(date_create(), date_create($data['PremiumStartTime']))->days
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I am using an SQL server, is this `datediff(now()...)` good for that? Also, now I'll have to edit this as well? `'days_remaining'        => number_format($data['DaysRemaining'])` is that correct? Thank you!

Comment: Amended above to work with SQL Server instead of MySQL

Comment: Thank you a lot. Before I accept it, could you please let me know which way - SQL or PHP is better in terms of overall performance?

Comment: There's basically no difference when you're doing it one row at a time like this. Personally I would do it in the SQL to keep the code simple.

Comment: I just tested the SQL code and it gives a 500 HTTP error. I changed `now()` to `getdate()` for a test and the website loads but shows the remaining days incorrectly. So, the problem is in `now()` ?

Comment: @Plar625 `now()` doesn't exist in sql-server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385042/sql-server-equivalent-of-mysqls-now.

Comment: @user3783243 - So the above code is correct except the `now()` ? If I change it to `getdate()` it loads but shows the remaining days incorrectly.

Comment: apologies, I originally wrote for MySQL and then hastily changed to SQL server. It is fixed now. SQL Server uses `getdate()` instead of `now()` and you have to switch around the arguments inside `date_diff`

Comment: Thanks, it works but lastly, it's not accurate? I mean it's not checking actual clock right? For example, I have in database `PremiumStartTime: 2018-12-17 21:13:00` and `PremiumDays: 28` and it shows remaining `25` when it should be `26` because server time is 12:40 AM at this moment, right?

Comment: @lufc - The PHP method shows it correctly as `26` days remaining. Is it safe to use the PHP method you provided above, I mean there shouldn't be any big difference compared to the SQL one? Thanks!

Comment: It is safe to use it. If your database server is in a different timezone to your web server you will get different results. If you use PHP to create the PremiumStartTime, use the PHP. If you use SQL to create the PremiumStartTime, use the SQL.

Comment: (PS if server time is 2018-12-20 00:40:00 then 25 is the correct result as you're now 3 days after the start date)

Comment: @lufc - Thanks, and also lastly, I tested the php code you provided and if I change  the `PremiumStartTime` from last month November like that: `2018-11-17 21:13:00` it still shows `26` days. Same for `2018-12-17 21:13:00` which is December. Do you know why is that happening? I believe it will happen the same thing with the SQL code too?

Comment: @lufc - I believe the part `->format('%d')` is doing the trouble. Is there any way to edit it, so it won't cause the trouble mentioned above?

Comment: You're right, sorry it should be `->days` or `->format('%r%a')`